# Execute tests with the same browser type concurrently which use the same cookies?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Execute tests with the same browser type concurrently which use the same cookies?

1. Scenario: Run multiple tests (x3) as the same time which all use firefox.
2. Currently if a item gets added to the basket it causes the tests to fail because all instances of the browser are using the same cookies.
3. Is it possible to use the same browser more than once at the same time even if web cookies are involved?
4. Maybe require the use of browser profiles?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but first idea is to use different user (who is logged in to firefox) for each test. I think they should have different cookies.